# Using a Response to create a table React JS dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, styled-components

I am currently getting a response that returns an array  like this

```
 const response = [{
    time: 1,
    speed: 2,
    direction:3,
    image:'url'

    
  },{
    time: 1,
    speed: 2,
    direction:3,
image:'url'
  },{
    time: 1,
    speed: 2,
    direction:3,
    image:'url'
    
  },{
    time: 1,
    speed: 2,
    direction:3,
image:'url' 
  }]
```

How do I make a table which the first column contains  only the names of the properties.
then subsequent columns  contain the data from the response respectively using the image URL as a header I have never used  tables in JS before. It also needs to be dynamic so that any number of of results from the response can be generated  with any number of keys from the object as all objects in the array will have the same keys

Ideally I want the table to look like this I know it is simple but it is really frustrating so any help would be appreciated

```
            image           image           image 
time          1               1               1 
speed         2               2               2
direction     3               3               3
```

Comment: What kind of JavaScript data structure would best support that table (for you)? That's half of the question.

Comment: I dont understand your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want. You can iterate over the keys and values of the object.

```
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td />
        {response.map((el) => (
          <td>{el.image}</td>
        ))}
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {Object.keys(response[0])
        .filter((k) => k !== "image")
        .map((k) => (
          <tr>
            <td>{k}</td>
            {response.map((r) => (
              <td>{r[k]}</td>
            ))}
          </tr>
        ))}
    </tbody>
  </table>
```